# Polarization on complex tori in Mumfords Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

In David Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes" in
Lecture IV: The Torelli Theorem and the
Schottky Problem of the Appendix on page 271 is described a condition
when for $g \ge 2$ and lattice $L \subset \mathbb{C}^g$
the complex torus $X= \mathbb{C}^g/L$ becomes projective variety.
The necessary and sufficient ingredient is the
existence of a positive definite Hermitian form $H$ on $ \mathbb{C}^g $
such that $E:= Im (H)$ is integral on $L \times L$. Such complex tori $X$
are called *abelian varieties*. The forms $H$ are called *polarizations* of $X$.

Questions:

**A** By definition $H: \mathbb{C}^g \times \mathbb{C}^g \to \mathbb{C}$.
What does it mean that "$E:= Im (H)$ is *integral* on $L \times L$"?
Does this conditions literally say that the image
$H(L \times L) \subset \mathbb{C}$
is contained in $\mathbb{Z} \subsetneqq \mathbb{C}$? If not,
what is the meaning of the quoted sentence?

**B** About polarizations in general. The text says
"The forms $H$ are called polarizations of $X$". So literally a "polarization"
can be defined independ of theory of algebraic varieties with pure linear algebra methods as
a positive definite Hermitian bilinear form on a complex vector space
$\mathbb{C}^n$, as far right?

Moreover the name "polarization" sounds very geometrical. Is there
any way how to think about such polarization?
Does there exist probably any archetypical example that
motivates & justifies the naming "polarization"?

Comment: A: Yes. B: For a general projective variety, the equivalent of a polarization is a Kahler metric whose cohomology class is integral. That is equivalent to it being the curvature form of a positive (thus ample) line bundle on the variety.

Comment: Hi, then last equivalence I not understand. Why a Kahler metric with *integral* cohomology class is equivalent to a curvature form of a positive line bundle? Which role plays here on the 'left hand side' that the coh class is *integral*?

Comment: The curvature form represents the first Chern class of the bundle, so its cohomology class is integral. It’s a lemma of Weil (proved in Huybrechts, I think, but the proof is just by Cech cohomology and the $\partial\bar\partial$ lemma) that given a form that represents the first Chern class of a line bundle there exists a metric on the bundle whose curvature form is that form. We also need that an integral $(1,1)$-class is the first Chern class of a line bundle, which follows from the exponential sequence.

Comment: Thank you, it becomes clearer now. Do you maybe know something about the origin of this name 'polarization' in this context? Although this souds like a concept having a natural geometric (preassumingly physical) origin, I haven't found anything in literature giving a satifying answer

Comment: There has been some discussion of Question B on MathOverflow; While I don't think there has been a conclusive answer reached, the terminology seems to be due to Weil in the context of Abelian varieties, and has spread to more general varieties. To me the word "polarization" suggests a choice of direction like with an electric current, so my guess is that the word is meant to be similar to but somehow different from "orientation." I suppose it you could think of a polarization as a choice of ray in the cone of ample divisors on $X$, which is literally a direction in the Neron-Severi space.

Comment: That looks like a nice intuition (assuming I understand it correctly). When you talk
about a 'ray' in the cone of ample divisors (in Neron-Severi space) you already
mean the Neron-Severi tensored by real numbers, like here
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nef_line_bundle#The_nef_cone), right?
Also, you say that you *not* associate to a polarization a *single* point
in the $\mathbb{R} \otimes NS$ but a complete ray.

Comment: Why? I thought that
following Gunnar's explanations polarization can be identified with a 
curvature form of certain ample line bundle. Isn't the choice of such ample line bundle 
unique? Or does the related curvature depends only on the *class* of every ample bundle
lying on same ray and it doesn't matter which positive integral point (= ample bundle) on the ray we choose ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Looking at at least one batch of definitions, I suppose I was thinking of principal (degree $1$) polarizations, of which I think there is at most one in a given ray. Also, here is the MO thread I referenced before: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177208/why-polarization-of-abelian-varieties